# Need all results from double left join

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have two tables.  One with transactions, including written cheques and corresponding ReceiptID, and another with written cheques only.  However, not all of the written cheques are in the transaction table. I want to join the two and get all of the written cheques and ReceiptID (which is only in the written cheques table).

**Table - Cheques**

Fields
 - LoanNo   ChequeNo    FieldA  FieldB  FieldC

**Table - Transactions**

Fields
 - LoanNo   ReceiptID   ChequeNo    FiledZ  FieldY

I was thinking that a

```
SELECT 
      .., 
      ReceiptID 
   FROM 
      Cheques 
         LEFT JOIN Transactions 
            ON Transactions.LoanNO =Cheques.LoanNo 
           AND Transactions.ChequeNo = Cheques.ChequeNo
```

should work, but it doesn't. At least not the way I had hoped. If a certain cheque is in the **Cheques** table but not in the **Transactions** table, it doesn't show in this query.  My expectation is that the record would show, but without a corresponding ReceiptNo, which is what I want.

Example

CHEQUES TABLE

```
╔════════╦══════════╦════════╗
║ LoanNo ║ ChequeNO ║ Amount ║
╠════════╬══════════╬════════╣
║   4444 ║    77777 ║     50 ║
║   5555 ║    99999 ║     60 ║
║   6666 ║   454545 ║    100 ║
╚════════╩══════════╩════════╝
```

TRANSACTIONS TABLE

```
+========+==========+========+===========+
| LoanNo | ChequeNO | Amount | ReceiptID |
+========+==========+========+===========+
|   4444 |    77777 |     50 | A5522     |
+--------+----------+--------+-----------+
|   5555 |    99999 |     60 | B6688     |
+--------+----------+--------+-----------+
```

The joined query does not give the record with ChequeNo 454545, What I want from the join is:

```
+========+==========+========+===========+
| LoanNo | ChequeNO | Amount | ReceiptID |
+========+==========+========+===========+
|   4444 |    77777 |     50 | A5522     |
+--------+----------+--------+-----------+
|   5555 |    99999 |     60 | B6688     |
+--------+----------+--------+-----------+
|   6666 |   454545 |    100 |           |
+--------+----------+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: Use Access query designer and modify the JOIN to be whichever is "Include all records from Cheques and only those from Transactions that match".

Comment: Could LoanNo not be in Cheques?

Comment: You don't clearly explain what you want. Please give a [mcve]. PS Format code inline using `\`backquotes\`` & as a block via indenting four spaces. Consider short table aliases.

Comment: @philipxy, I thought I did explain what I want.  I want the query to give me all of the records in the 'Cheques' table, including the ReceiptID from the 'Transactions' table.  Where there is no corresponding Cheque record in the 'Transactions', then that result field shoulid be empty but the result should still give the records from the 'Cheques' table.

Comment: using the "include all records from the Cheques and only those from the Transactions that match" does not do what I want.  It actually excludes the records in the Cheques table that are not in the Transactions table.

Comment: Example

 CHEQUES 
+--------+----------+--------+
| LoanNo | ChequeNO | Amount |
+--------+----------+--------+
|   4444 |    77777 |     50 |
|   5555 |    99999 |     60 |
|   6666 |   454545 |    100 |
+--------+----------+--------+

 TRANSACTIONS  

+--------+----------+--------+-----------+
| LoanNo | ChequeNO | Amount | ReceiptID |
+--------+----------+--------+-----------+
|   4444 |    77777 |     50 | A5522     |
|   5555 |    99999 |     60 | B6688     |
+--------+----------+--------+-----------+

Comment: The joined query does not give the record with ChequeNo 454545

What I want from the join is:
Result
+--------+----------+--------+-----------+
| LoanNo | ChequeNO | Amount | ReceiptID |
+--------+----------+--------+-----------+
|   4444 |    77777 |     50 | A5522     |
|   5555 |    99999 |     60 | B6688     |
|   6666 |   454545 |    100 |           |
+--------+----------+--------+-----------+

Comment: @user2588110 the example does not make sense. Where does LoanNo 6666 come from? Where is ChequeNo 454545 in the Cheques table?

Comment: Please clarify via post edits, not comments. Once those comments are in your post (maybe they are now) please delete them. Re "I thought I did explain what I want": You were not clear enough to be useful. It does not say how to join them. You need to describe the output in terms of the input clearly engough that just using that description someone could code the query. You still haven't. It can help to also clearly reference parts of examples. PS Please google 'stackexchange notifications' to learn to use `@` to notify someone of a comment when not the poster or sole non-poster commenter.

Comment: A [mcve] includes DBMS (with version), a clear specification, cut & paste & runnable code (with small representative input) (format table initializations as tables) & diffable (hence ordered) desired output. But absolute basics of debugging say: Show that your program does what you expect as it goes through (sub)expressions by saying what that is & showing that it actually does it via incremental output. On adding problem code that you can't fix, research (the manual & the web). Repeat, minimizing working & wrong code. Then ask re the (small) difference between working & non-working examples.

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN returns: INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Just to comment.  Instead of long comments, try to EDIT your existing question with additional details and such, format as needed and comment back something like "changes / requests added to original post"... Hard to read feedback and additional data in such comment areas.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.  After being pretty sure that what I expected to happen should happen, I closed MS Access and relaunched it.  Then the SQL worked as expected.  No idea why it didn't work before.

```
SELECT Cheques.*, Transactions.ReceiptID
FROM Cheques LEFT JOIN Transactions ON Transactions.ChequeNo = Cheques.ChequeNo AND Transactions.LoanNo = Cheques.LoanNo
```